# Changing all vlookup formats in text format

Tags: vba, excel

I am vlooking up values from an excel sheet (they are in column I and J as it is obvious from code) that are either dates or numbers or text. I am trying to change the formats of these values to text, so as to vlookup the value of the cell as it is shown. So if I see 28/07/2018, I want to vlookup it as it is and not get as a vlookup result a number or a date(which most of the time is automatically transfered as a number). What I have tried so far is given below but it does not work well.

```
ws3.Range("I2:J" & lastrow1).NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Make the format of the cell containing the `VLOOKUP()` formula the same as the format of the cells in the column you are returning data from.  If the column returned is variable, then a `UDF()` is a possible solution.

Comment: but the column I am returning data from has different formats, not just one.. thats why I want to change the column format to text but, when I do that the dates are replaced by numbers

Comment: Great!  the `UDF()` can retrieve data by getting the cell's **address**.  This means it can get the cell's format as well as its value and return the result in the desired format...................is a VBA version of `VLOOKUP()` acceptable??

Comment: yes it is acceptable! Can you please explain further how to use this UDF?

Comment: Once I have written the `UDF()`, I'll include instruction.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent how do you plan on changing the target cells format to the format of the lookup cell.  As far as I know a UDF can't do that.

Comment: @ScottCraner  The `UDF()`  will return pure Text as the cell's format won't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start out with a little table:

[image]

As you see, the items in column **H** have varying formats; date formats, number formats, and currency formats.

Our code is:

```
Public Function vbaLookup(valu As Variant, rng As Range, icol As Long) As String
    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long

    LastRow = rng.Rows.Count
    FirstRow = 1

    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        If valu = rng(1).Offset(i - 1, 0) Then
            vbaLookup = rng(1).Offset(i - 1, icol - 1).Text
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    vbaLookup = "xxxx"
End Function
```

- The first argument is the lookup value
- the second argument is the table range
- the third argument is the column indicator.

In the example shown below, we place in cell **C1** the formula:

```
=vbaLookup("gamma",G1:I3,2)
```

What we get is:

[image]

As you see, the proper format gets picked up !!
  *NOTE:  There are limitations....it won't pick up underlining or font colors or cell background colors, etc.*

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to **install** and use:

1. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>  brings up the VBE window
2. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
   <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the UDF from Excel:

```
=vbaLookup("gamma",G1:I3,2)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thats really awesome! Thanks a lot! Real MVP!

Comment: @Jonnyboi  Thanks..........try it out and let me know if you find any bugs..............